# Creating a JDBC connection to Athena doesn't work

Tags: amazon-web-services, jdbc, amazon-athena, sql-workbench-j

I have a DB on Athena up and running, and now I'm trying to connect to it using SQLWorkbenchJ. I downloaded the [JDBC drivers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/connect-with-jdbc.html) provided by AWS, added it to my workbench setup - but it just won't connect. The exact error message is

> [Simba][AthenaJDBC] An error has been thrown from the AWS Athena client. **The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided**. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method.

The URL I'm connecting to is `jdbc:awsathena://athena.[my-region].amazonaws.com:443`

I've added the `S3OutputLocation` key as specified, and the IAM user has the necessary policies attached to it. Anyone have any clue what I'm missing?

Comment: Double-check the access key and particularly the secret key you are using. And verify them with another client, for example the awscli (e.g. aws athena ...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the error was because AWS appends a space to the access key when copying from the web UI. For anyone who runs into this error, please try creating a new pair of credentials, downloading them as a CSV file and then **explicitly copying the keys** to your Workbench. Worked for me.